# Define custom font-face for uppercase text

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

As I know, CSS allows to define custom fonts for different `font-weight`.

For example I have defined 3 different `@font-face` under same `font-family`, but different `font-weight` property:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('../fonts/font-light.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('../fonts/font-regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('../fonts/font-bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and depending what `font-weight` I'll use, corresponding `.woff` will be loaded:

```
//font-light.woff is used
p {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    font-weight: 300;
}

//font-regular.woff is used
p {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    font-weight: normal;
}

//font-bold.woff is used
p {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is good, but I stack on how to define custom font-face for UPPERCASE text.
Right now, Georgian uppercase is not yet included in Unicode standard, so I have to load different font file for uppercase font variant.

My idea is to load custom `.woff` when `text-transform: uppercase` is defined in element styles.

I played with `text-transform` and `font-feature-settings` in `@font-face` declaration, but with no luck.

Is it possible to achieve somehow with pure css?

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
font-variant: small-caps;
```

or

```
-moz-font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
-webkit-font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
-ms-font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
font-feature-settings: 'smcp';
```

or an SC version of the font if it exists.

Comment: Does this feature work for any OpenType font or font must have some specific feature support?
Thanks

Comment: @zur4ik not all OpenType fonts have small caps alternates.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend including the desired font as usual, and simply only opting to reference it in combination with **[`text-transform: uppercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform)**. This way, it will only ever be applied to uppercase characters.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

.roboto {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="regular">Regular</div>
<div class="roboto">Roboto</div>
```

Comment: That's nice :) but this works for English characters, not Georgian.
for example with `text-transform: uppercase` you still have lowercase  "ქართული"

Comment: Not sure about the specifics of Georgian sorry, but you could always just make use of a specific `.class` for elements that you write uppercase characters into manually :) For example, `<div class="uppercase">UPPERCASE</div>`. The principle is exactly the same; as long as you only use the class `.uppercase` when you actually write the characters in uppercase, it's the only element that will have the font applied :)